# NodeJS: util.inspect object with function inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, deserialization

I have an object like so:

```
  const foo = {
    bar: "bar value",

    baz() {
      console.log(this.bar);
    },
  };
```

I want to write this object to a separate js file using `fs.writeFileSync` and `util.inspect`

e.g.

```
fs.writeFileSync("newfile.js", "exports.config = " + 
util.inspect(foo, { showHidden: false, compact: false, depth: null }));
```

Which gets me the file `newfile.js` with the following contents:

```
exports.config = {
  bar: 'bar value',
  baz: [Function: baz]
}
```

I need to function `baz` to be exposed like how it was exposed in the original object `foo` and not shown as `[Function: baz]`. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky, but since you're doing this on Node.js, you don't have to worry about vagaries of different JavaScript engines, which is good.

You'll need to use the recently-standardized `Function.prototype.toString`. Your `baz` is a *method* and so `toString` returns a method definition for it, but other functions may come through as function declarations, function expressions, arrow functions, etc.

This should get you started:

```
const strs = [];
for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(foo)) {
    if (typeof value === "function") {
        const fstr = value.toString().trim();
        if (fstr.startsWith("function") || fstr[0] === "(") {
            strs.push(`${name}: ${fstr}`);
        } else {
            strs.push(fstr); // probably a method
        }
    } else {
        strs.push(`${name}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
    }
}
const sep = "\n    ";
const str = `exports.config = {${sep}${strs.join(`,${sep}`)}\n};`;
```

Live Example (if you're not using a browser that has V8 — like Chrome, Chromium, Brave — then this may not work):

```js
const foo = {
    bar: "bar value",

    biz: function() {
        // This is a function assigned to a property
        return this.bar;
    },
    
    buz: function() {
        // This is an arrow function assigned to a property
        // VERY surprising that this comes out as a traditional function
        return this.bar.toUpperCase();
    },
    
    baz() {
        // This is a method
        console.log(this.bar);
    },
};
const strs = [];
for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(foo)) {
    if (typeof value === "function") {
        const fstr = value.toString().trim();
        if (fstr.startsWith("function") || fstr[0] === "(") {
            strs.push(`${name}: ${fstr}`);
        } else {
            strs.push(fstr); // probably a method
        }
    } else {
        strs.push(`${name}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
    }
}
const sep = "\n    ";
const str = `exports.config = {${sep}${strs.join(`,${sep}`)}\n};`;
console.log(str);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Obviously there's a lot of room for improvement in there (for instance, what if there's a function in an object assigned to one of `foo`'s properties?), it's just intended to give you a starting-off point.